# How to package resources, that are accessed directly , into a jar file

Tags: java, jar, resources, runnable, slick2d

I have recently developed a game in Slick2D, i have accessed all my images directly e.g

```
Image i = new Image("address.png");
```

as opposed to using a class that will load resources or using an input stream.

I wondered if it would still be possible to load all the resources into a jar, i added the `/res` folder to my buildpath and used jarsplice to add my libraries and natives however the jar will not run because it cannot find the images.

Comment: You should use <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)">getResourceAsStream()</a> or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Image i = new Image("address.png");
```

Is looking into the root filesystem where your application is running. If you want to use the resources packed in your jarfile you must do:

```
Image i = new Image(getClass().getResource("/res/address.png").toURI()); // In case your Image object accepts URI as parameters
```

**EDIT**

```
Image i = new Image(getClass().getResource("/res/address.png").toExternalForm()); // Since your object only accept Strings
```

Comment: Bruno, will the 2nd option work universally, i.e. when you are running the app out of the compiled classes (e.g. Eclipse run/debug) as well as running it out of the jar?

Comment: Yes, it surely will. BTW, which Image object is this one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however when i do this i get an error will this method work with the org.newdawn.slick.Image version of image?

Comment: THANKYOU I am a bit of a noob at exporting and this has helped alot thanks :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct. Otherwise stackoverflow will never know that your problems has being solved. Besides that, you earn reputation by accepting an answer (and so does who answered)

Comment: Actually - sorry to be a trouble , but it still isnt working - i dont get an error until i run it and then i get

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Main.Menu.init(Menu.java:44)
 at Main.MainClass.initStatesList(MainClass.java:28)
 at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:164)
 at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390)
 at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)
 at Main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:40)

Comment: Post your line 40 from your MainClass.java here

Comment: appgc.start();  so i guess there is an issue with the entire program because this method of loading resources isn't compatible with Slick

Comment: Post Line 28 (Sorry, I mean 28 in my last comment, just got distracted)

Comment: this.getState(menu).init(gc, this); this is where i call the class menu (where i am using this technique)

Comment: BTW, post it as another question with your whole main.java file. It seems it doesn't have to do anymore with packaged resources

Comment: How to package resources, that are accessed directly , into a jar file - Full Source Code