# Make a jar library with working resource files

Tags: java, jar, resources

I have made some kind of library, and it needs some xml files so i have stored them in a resource folder and i load it like it like this:

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/somefile.xml");
```

Everything works fine when running from the same jar. However, if i decide to export this code as a .jar and import it as an external jar from another program, the above code fails to get the resource.
How can i do this correctly?

Note: Actually the jar file is an android library jar (android project marked as library in eclipse), it seems to work fine in my android app, but since it is just a library i want to test it out in a non android app, everything works fine except for getting the resource file.
Should i write the library as a simple java project?

Comment: What do you mean by "running from the same jar"?

Comment: Try this: [Forum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713861/how-to-package-resources-that-are-accessed-directly-into-a-jar-file)

Comment: Same jar = my main is in the same jar as the library.

Comment: If i import that jar from another program, as a library, the get resource fails

Comment: That does't work, its the same.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the Jar?  Are the resources being included?

Comment: Yup they are, i think the problem is that it is trying to access the file in a route that does not exist in the other jar.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shame on me, the resources files needed to be added to the src folder or any other folder set in the class path.